# eclipselink getResultCollection() not available to return a set

Tags: java, eclipselink

I'm trying to return a set instead of a list in eclipselink.
As noted [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_resultcollectiontype.htm) in order to return a collection one has to use `getResultCollection()` . However that method is not defined so I can't use it.

I've just switched from a library provided by user to a maven implementation and it doesn't change anything, I still can't use that method.

```
    <!-- eclipselink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you need a set?
The result of a query is always a list because it can be ordered and it may contain duplicate values.

Comment: Because I'm putting it in an hashset. It cannot contain duplicates as I'm querying whole entities (with Id). And I mean... the doc says I should be able to do it

Comment: Usually one uses JPA and there getResultList returns a list.

You can simply pass the list as parameter to the constructor of the HashSet

Comment: @simas_ch yeah that's what I did. However if the option is there (the doc says it is) then I'd use it

Comment: The point is that QueryHints are implementation internal stuff. So if you change the OR Mapper for example to Hibernate this code will break. It could also be possible if this changes in further EclipseLink versions and you will find the problem where late.

Comment: The doc is correct, so what problem are you having calling getResultCollection()?  I'm guessing you realize it is an EclipseLink method, not JPA, so that you must unwrap or cast your query to be able to use it.  If not, try using query.unwrap(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.class).getResultCollection();